# typescript new array with length

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular

I am using Angular 2 beta and Typescript (`"gulp-typescript": "~2.12.1",`).

I am writing a component for `<div qz-badge num-stars="3" class="qz-badge"></div>`

```
import {Component, Input, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: '[qz-badge]',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `
    <div class="stars">
    </div>
  `
})
export class Badge {
  @Input('num-stars') numStars: number;

  constructor() {
    console.log(new Array(3));
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    let num = this.numStars;
    console.log(num);

    console.log('--------');
    this.stars = new Array(num);
    console.log(this.stars);
    console.log(this.stars.length);

    num = 3;
    console.log('--------');
    this.stars = new Array(num);
    console.log(this.stars);
    console.log(this.stars.length);
  }
}
```

It leads ..

```
3
--------
["3"]
1
--------
[]
3
```

In the specification,

Syntax

```
[element0, element1, ..., elementN]
new Array(element0, element1[, ...[, elementN]])
new Array(arrayLength)
```

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

I think the length should be 3.
Is that a bug or is there some righteous reasons?

Comment: Although `numStars` is defined as number, it acted like a string so `console.log(this.numStars+1)` was 31, not 4 and I couldn't `ParseInt`. `let num = +this.numStars;` finally led 3-length array. It's weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's not a bug, it's simply as it works. All `@Input()`'s are passed as strings. As Rob Wormald's states in this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6919).

> Types in TS are purely a compile-time construct

So you won't have a number at runtime, but a string, even if you specify `number` as your Input's type. So you can cast it using `parseInt`.

```
// this.numStars is a string, not a number
let num = parseInt(this.numStars);
```

And that'll make it work correctly.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/J6nij14uM3BVJRh9c4O7?p=preview) with your case working.

**Edit**

I missed something in your code. You're passing the value with no binding (no brackets), so it's not getting evaluated. It's a raw string.

The above answer is still valid, but in your case is much easier by passing the value with binding

```
[num-stars]="3"
```

Here's another [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sIxkt7GQXPhT0jZHmUuz?p=preview) without the parseInt but using binding.

Comment: Thank you, I understood Angular can pass it as a string in that case. and I agree with it's not a bug. BTW, in my case, I couldn't `parseInt` because of `error TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not signable to parameter of type 'string'.`, but `let num = +this.numStars;` worked. I rather define `numStars` as a `any`, not a `string`.